# I want to create a popup when I click on button using Jquery

Tags: jquery, popup

When I click on the button with the code below popup should come. I need to create a popup asking are you a new customer or existing customer something like that when i click on button. How can I proceed doing that. Help should be appreciated.

```
<a style="display: inline-block; width: 85px; font-weight: normal;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('mrpPhones$ctl06$lineItemPrice$lnkbtnAddToCart','')" class="button-genericsprite green-button-23cart" title="Add to cart" id="mrpPhones_ctl06_lineItemPrice_lnkbtnAddToCart" onclick="javascript:hideProgressBar();return openPlanChangeRequiredPopup('cd244ed6-7afc-4db5-bf764b7de21c9003','https://s.tmocache.com/images/png/products/phones/LG_Optimus_T_Black/110x110.png');">
    <span style="font-size: 12px;">Add to Cart</span>
</a>
```

Comment: <a style="display: inline-block; width: 85px; font-weight: normal;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('mrpPhones$ctl08$lineItemPrice$lnkbtnAddToCart','')" class="button-genericsprite green-button-23cart" title="Add to cart" id="mrpPhones_ctl08_lineItemPrice_lnkbtnAddToCart" onclick="javascript:hideProgressBar();">
                        <span style="font-size: 12px;">Add to Cart</span>           
                    </a>

Comment: Why have you copied your code into a comment? It messes up the page's feng shui

Comment: What do you mean by "a popup"? A modal dialog? An alert? A window?

Comment: Well if you really do mean an alert, then `alert("Whatever");` will do it... :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I would use a modal dialog from jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog#modal

Answer (score 0):

I think You need something like this

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "New Customer": function() {
                                    //Put Necessary codes here
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Existing customer": function() {
                                     //Put Necessary codes here
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="New or Existing Customer?">
<p>
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px
   0;">New or Existing Customer?
  </span>
</p>
</div>
```